# implicit declaration of function 'OSReadBigInt8' is invalid in c99

Tags: objective-c, endianness

OSReadBigInt8 doesn't seem to exist like those of OSReadBigInt16 and OSReadBigInt32. I would I convert a network byte into the endianess of my platform in objective c? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness is meaningless for a single byte.  Just copy it straight across.

```
uint8_t hostByte = networkByte;
```